# Mensagem de erro em formulário mesmo quando o envio é confirmado

Tags: html, jquery

Boa noite!

Desenvolvi um formulário, com ajuda de outros usuários daqui, para enviar novos registros ao sistema de CRM de um cliente. Quando realizamos um envio, os dados chegam ao CRM, mas o navegador acusa a mensagem de erro. Já fiz alguns testes, mas não consigo entender o que pode estar errado.

O código do meu formulário é o seguinte:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="unidade" name="unidade" value="XXX">
    <input type="hidden" id="chave" name="chave" value="XXX">
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="campos" placeholder="Seu nome" required>
</div>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="campos" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" class="campos" placeholder="Seu celular" required>
</div>    
<div width="100%" class="motivo">
    <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Selecionar">----- Selecione uma das opções</option>
    <option value="Concurso e vestibular">Concurso e vestibular</option>
    <option value="Inteligência">Inteligência</option>
    <option value="Memória">Memória</option>
    <option value="Profissional">Profissional</option>
    <option value="Alzheimer">Alzheimer</option>
    <option value="Ansiedade">Ansiedade</option>
    <option value="Atenção">Atenção</option>
    <option value="Estresse">Estresse</option>
    <option value="Estudo">Estudo</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div width="100%" align="center">
    <button onClick="form()" id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" class="btn-enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function form () {
        $("#formulario").on('submit', function (event) {

            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
            var observacoes = $("#observacoes").val();  
            var unidade = $("#unidade").val();
            var chave = $("#chave").val();


            $.get( `https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/${nome};${email};${telefone};${observacoes}/${unidade}/${chave}/`)
            .done(function( data ) {
                alert("Sucesso");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Erro" );
            })

            event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
</script>
```

A página é a seguinte: https://superaguaruja.com.br/teste/

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um teste no seu código para envio, e verifiquei que a resposta de erro é a seguinte:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/teste;teste;teste;Aten%C3%A7%C3%A3o/281/321498639/' from origin 'https://superaguaruja.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Isso indica que o navegador não conseguiu acessar o link do CRM devido a um bloqueio de CORS. Isso acontece porque o link no qual você está conectando não tem o mesmo domínio que seu site. Se quiser saber mais sobre o CORS, dá uma olhadinha em: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS

Nesse caso, você teria que habilitar certas permissões no CRM que recebe esses dados, mas como esse é provavelmente um sistema fechado, o mais adequado seria montar um código que recebe esses dados e os repassam ao link do CRM, dentro do seu próprio site.

Assim, a requisição seria feita para uma URL do seu próprio site, evitando problemas de cross-origin. Se você estiver utilizando PHP, por exemplo, pode montar um código que recebe os dados o formulário e depois executa um curl, enviando os dados do formulário para esse link, mas tudo dentro do PHP!

Lembre-se também que colocando um código "intermediário", como citei acima, é muito mais seguro, pois você não expõe o link direto do CRM aos usuários da página.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pelo direcionamento! Vou fazer alguns testes por aqui, e no paralelo vou sinalizar pro pessoal do CRM essa questão.